# onActivityResult not called in Fragment

Tags: android-studio, zbar

In my fragment onActivityResult is not calling after     startActivityForResult .As i have tried following things:
1) adding getParentFragment , getActivity before startActivityResult

2) added on manifest  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

3)[onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

4)Checked finish () method in ZbarScanner Activity

```
Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
                    dataIntent.putExtra(SCAN_RESULT, symData);
                    dataIntent.putExtra(SCAN_RESULT_TYPE, sym.getType());
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataIntent);
                    finish();
```

5) Error- [ResultInfo{who=null, request=196609, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }}]} checked intent has value not null which we are passing

```
if (isCameraAvailable()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), ZBarScannerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.QRCODE});

                  startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "inside case", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Rear Facing Camera Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

----onActivityResult------

```
  @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();


            switch (requestCode) {
                case ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST:
                case ZBAR_QR_SCANNER_REQUEST:
                    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {


                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Scan Result = " + data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
                        String error = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.ERROR_INFO);
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(error)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called onActivityResult on MainActivity and with  this its not calling .so removed switch case .and its working now

```
switch (requestCode) {
            case ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST:
            case ZBAR_QR_SCANNER_REQUEST:
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very common and known issue for fragment `onActivityResult`. I have solved it in one way, there might be other ways also.

set tag when you are moving to `Fragment` from `Activity` like this.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment,"tag").commit();
```

now write below code in your `onActivityResult` of `Activity`.

```
 if (requestCode == 1) { //set your requestcode whichever you are using
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
        //dont forget to comment this.

        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
        if(fragment != null){
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
}
```

Comment: As we are not replacing it . We are calling this fragment like this in tabs  class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new FirstFragment();
                case 1 : return new SecondFragment();
                case 2 : return new ThirdFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }so is there any way to call the fragment as you mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while working with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` inside a Fragment. The problem was that I initialized my `PagerAdapter` with the Fragment's  `FragmentManager`, I replaced:

```
new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

with

```
new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

So it might be worth checking which FragmentManager you are using. I'm not 100% happy with this approach yet as it seems right to call the Fragment's `FragmentManager`. But I did not get the time to check it any further yet.